# Positioning horizontal menu using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to do fixed menu using flexbox. In my navigation bar I created 2 divs. First should contain logo, and second menu(with `display:flex` property). I've got problem, when I want to postion the li element of my menu. I want horizontal menu, but when I add `justify-content:space-between` my first element should be situated in left edge of menu's div but it has a small margin and I don't know why.

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lmu08yc/

```css
header {
    height:100vh;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:100vw;
    max-width:100%;

}

.navbar {
    width:100vw;
    background-color:grey;
    height:7vh;
    max-width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    border-bottom:5px solid white; 
    z-index:2;

}

.flex_row {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}

.container{
    height:100%;
    width:100vw;
    max-width:100%;
    background-color:green;
    display:flex;
}


#logo {
    height:100%;
    background-color:white;
    flex-grow:1;
}

#menu {
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    flex-grow:1;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    align-content:flex-end;

}

#menu ul li {

    border:1px solid black;
    line-height:40px;
}
```

```html
<header>
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar flex_row">
    <div id  ="logo"></div>
    <div id ="menu">
        <ul class="flex_row">
            <li><a href="#">text1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">text2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">text3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">text4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Share your full code and mention what error exactly you are getting.

Comment: Looks like you just forg0t to zero out the margins & padding - https://jsfiddle.net/bwpg01b0/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have to add margin:0; to '#menu ul'.

HTML automatically adds a margin to unorderded lists.

```
#menu ul {
      margin:0;
}
```